# 1024x768 on ipad using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

after a long day researching into why 1024x768 video would not work on an iPad 3, and a lot of forum hunting. I could not find any reasonable solutions to this problem. Seems a lot of people where having the same situation with only a black screen being shown.

Solution was to render out the video required as 1024x 748. Reason being the status bar shown at the top of an iPad is 20px.

I hope this solves a lot of user problems they are having with this situation.

**Onto my next question....**

I currently have a video embedded into my view via the MPMoviePlayerController. This video is on a constant loop(An animated menu). I then have three invisible buttons layered on top of the video to which methods are called. I only have one working at present, the other two just show alerts.

The problem I am having at present is that, when the button is clicked, I want another video to play. This is working perfectly, BUT i would like the first video to FIRST play to the end the go onto the play the next video, reason being, I need it too be seamless and not be obvious its going from one video to another.

**Any feedback on this would be great....**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "VideoPlayerViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController () 

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VideoPlayerViewController *myPlayerViewController;

@end


@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize playerViewController = _playerViewController;
@synthesize myPlayerViewController = _myPlayerViewController;

- (void)dealloc {
    self.playerViewController = nil;
    self.myPlayerViewController = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void)buttonEventOne:(id)sender {

    //[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"CONTENT ONE" message:@"This will link to content one video" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];


    NSURL *urlTwo = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BAE_BG_anim_pt2_748" withExtension:@"mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    playerViewController.contentURL = urlTwo;
    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    playerViewController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    //playerViewController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playerViewController play];

    self.playerViewController = playerViewController;
    [playerViewController release];


}

-(void)buttonEventTwo:(id)sender {

    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"CONTENT TWO" message:@"This will link to content one video" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}

-(void)buttonEventThree:(id)sender {

    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"CONTENT THREE" message:@"This will link to content one video" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BAE_Main_Loop_748" withExtension:@"mov"];

    // video player
    MPMoviePlayerController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.contentURL = url;
    [playerViewController prepareToPlay];
    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    playerViewController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    playerViewController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playerViewController play];

    self.playerViewController = playerViewController;
    [playerViewController release];

    UIButton * btnOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnOne.frame = CGRectMake(260, 350, 150, 50);
    [btnOne setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEventOne:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnOne];

    UIButton * btnTwo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnTwo.frame = CGRectMake(620, 350, 150, 50);
    [btnTwo setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEventTwo:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnTwo];

    UIButton * btnThree = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btnThree.frame = CGRectMake(450, 250, 150, 50);
    [btnThree setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnThree addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEventThree:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:btnThree];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || 
            interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
} 
@end
```

Comment: You might want to accept some of the answers people have posted to your previous questions, by clicking the outline of a 'tick' on the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: ah awesome I didnt realise you could do that!

Comment: This place is great, seems alot of people are willing to help or lend a hand, I hope the problem I had has solved alot of peoples issues with this black screen

Comment: Iv just had a thought on this problem, could I set a BOOL variable to be used inside buttonOne, to which once clicked would be set to YES, once variable == YES, play video to end, then goto and play next video???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried registering for playback notifications, specifically the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, catchy huh?  If you register for the notification when the button is hit:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  addObserver:self 
  selector:@selector(introMovieFinished:) 
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
  object:self.playerViewController];
```

Then in that function:

```
- (void)introMovieFinished:(NSNotification*)note {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    removeObserver:self 
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object:self.playerViewController];
  // Do stuff.
}
```

You de-register your interest in the notifications and then start playing the next movie.  Because you only register an interest when the button is hit you shouldn't receive the function call until the movie finishes.

Comment: ill give that a go mate, iv been at it today trying to figure out a solution for this. 

I ended up setting up a BOOL variable, which was the set to YES on the button. I then also set up a timer to which looks if that variable is == YES. Once it is == YES, it then sets the repeat mode to MPMovieRepeatModeNone. Once the video is then taken out of the loop, the timer then looks to see if the currentPlaybackTime of the video is == to the play length.